# Groovy: How does @Grab inclusion differ from classpath inclusion?

Tags: groovy, dependencies, classpath, groovy-grape

#### 1. Generally, how is @Grape/@Grab inclusion different than classpath inclusion?

#### 2. Specifically, what might cause the following behavior difference?

I've got a requirement on `xpp3` which I express as:

```
// TestScript.groovy
@Grab(group='xpp3', module='xpp3', version='1.1.3.4.O')
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
println "Created: " + XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
```

Running `$ groovy TestScript.groovy` fails with

> Caught: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:

If, however, I **manually add the .jar fetched by Grape to my Groovy classpath**:

```
$ groovy -cp ~/.groovy/grapes/xpp3/xpp3/jars/xpp3-1.1.3.4.O.jar \
         TestScript.groovy
```

... then everything works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Grab uses ivy to fetch the specified library (plus all of its dependencies) from the maven core repository. It then adds these downloaded libraries to the classpath of the loader that's running the current script.

Adding the jar to the classpath just adds the specified jar to the system classpath.

As there are no dependencies in this example, it's probably a requirement that the library needs to be loaded by the system classloader.

To check this, try adding

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader= true)
@Grab(group='xpp3', module='xpp3', version='1.1.3.4.O')
```

Instead of the one line Grab you currently have

Comment: That fixes my examples (so thanks!) But in the real world, xpp3 is a transitive dependency for me. If I add `systemClassLoader= true` to the `Grab` that transitively gets xpp3, I get a linkage error (`loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.getXMLReader()Lorg/xml/sax/XMLReader;`).  Ideas on this one?

Comment: Grab only goes so far, I'd move to a build tool like gradle

Comment: Hmm, OK. I just want to run a groovy script that requires one mvn-accessible jar and its transitive dependencies. (This works fine in grails-land...) You'd recommend gradle for this?

Comment: No if it's just one script (there's no mention of what you are doing or what library you're trying to load in the question). If Grab isn't working, you'll need to add them to the classpath yourself as you show in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It's just one script, but I'd like to distribute it in a way that users can execute that script themselves, without having to **manually** download a bunch of jars first.  `@Grab` would have been great. As is, I'm using a Gradle-based solution similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360719/running-groovy-scripts-from-gradle -- which works okay but I'd be very interested to know if you think there' a better way!

Comment: Can you give a small failing example script in the question?

Comment: Aha -- looks like I just had two conflicting transitive dependencies.  `systemClassLoader=true` was the real trick (and then, excluding one of the dependencies). Thanks again!