# Use compiled class in a gradle build script

Tags: gradle

I am trying to get a gradle task to evaluate a static field in a class that was compiled in the same build file but I have not found a way to achieve that without doing stuff like JavaExec and have a Java main or a Groovy script output something to stdout (something like [Running Groovy scripts from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360719/running-groovy-scripts-from-gradle)). Is there a way to evaluate a Java or Groovy expression in a task and set the classpath to the compile or runtime classpath of the project? The task would depend on compileJava, so I can be sure the code is compiled before the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? Specifically, why does the class with the static field need to be in the main sourceset?

Comment: This class holds an internal version number in a static member that is used to locate a native library. Since the build script also has to do things based on that version number I want to eliminate the duplication as a source of errors. Technically it does not seem such a big deal but so far I have only got it to work evaluating a groovy script in the main sourceSet which is misleading as this code is part of the build process and not of the product that is built.

Comment: I'd consider removing the duplication by holding the version number in the build script and generating the class.

Comment: That's a possibility. If that class were not mine, (i.e. an external library) would there be a way, i.e. is there an answer to my original question, regardless of whether it is the way I should do it or not?