# How to start groovy script from gradle build script?

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-studio

I try to define some groovy module that has 2 different scripts near from  `apply plugin: 'android'` in Android Studio, but I receive an Error. As I found, `apply plugin: 'android'` and `apply plugin: 'groovy'` are incompatible, for this reason I starting my scripts like:

```
def gse = new GroovyScriptEngine([pathToFolderOfScript] as String[])
gse.run('LoadJsonFromServer.groovy', new Binding())
```

Is there any another more elegant way? Such as this, for exmaple: [Running Groovy scripts from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360719/running-groovy-scripts-from-gradle?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: You can add the scripts, as a plain tasks for instance. Or methods in build.gradle.

Comment: I forgot to say, that I have some `Grapes`dependencies in my scripts

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that every user has groovy installed the following script will work:

**build.gradle**

```
task runScript (type: Exec) {
   commandLine  'groovy', '<PATH_TO_SCRIPTS>/myscript.groovy'// it's good idea to take the script path from env variable
}
```

**myscript.groovy**

```
@Grab(group='org.springframework', module='spring', version='2.5.6')
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate

def tmpl = new JdbcTemplate()

println tmpl.hashCode()
```

Comment: You should just use the Groovy which Gradle itself uses, not expect users to install Groovy in their machines.

Answer (score 1):

```
Eval.me(new File("path/to/file").text)
```

Comment: For more advanced use cases, see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy

Comment: I suppose it will not work with `Grapes` dependency resolution.

Comment: did you try? I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried without success. I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport`, so it seems CP problem only. Nevertheless it requires additional work.

Comment: This works just fine from the groovy console. I think you might need to update your version of Gradle?

Comment: Ok, what is the content of the file You're evaluating? If You put `Grapes` code, copy my sample script, it won't work. I've gradle 2.1.

Comment: I found that Gradle has a limited version of Groovy: http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/problem-with-gradle-and-groovy-scripts-with-Grapes-td3315546.html So if you want to make this work, you should explicitly set your version of Groovy for Gradle to use. Hope you can figure out how to do that.

Comment: My bet is: add a "buildScript" dependency on groovy-all.

Comment: The problem is that the code is not working without using gradle. Nevermind. Forget about it.