# Include dependencies in Groovy application without repository access

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I have a Groovy project (using Eclipse) which makes use of several `@Grab` statements. This works fine on my development machine. However I need to distribute this application including all its dependencies to other machines which don't have any internet connection, i.e. it won't be possible to download the necessary JARs from these machines.

Is there a way to somehow automatically include the dependencies into the project, e.g. a `lib` folder? This way I could just copy the project to another machine and use it.

Comment: Download the dependencies and put them in a lib folder maybe?  Sounds like you are looking for a build tool.  Have you looked at gradle? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html

Comment: I would explore creating an uberjar. I haven't tried it myself with Groovy. With regular java it's straightforward with Maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, lets say for example you have a script `Script.groovy` like so, that you currently run with `groovy Script.groovy`:

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.rest.*

def client = new RESTClient("http://httpbin.org")
def response = client.get(path:'/get')

assert 200 == response.statusCode
println "Received : $response.json"
```

Now, we want to get this into a jar file that you can distribute, and people can just run with `java -jar myApp.jar`

So make the following folder structure:

```
myApp
 |-- src
 |    |-- main
 |         |-- groovy
 |              |-- example
 |                   |-- Script.groovy
 |-- build.gradle
```

Then, in `Script.groovy`, put your script (with a package name, and no `@Grab` annotation):

```
package example

import wslite.rest.*

def client = new RESTClient("http://httpbin.org")
def response = client.get(path:'/get')

assert 200 == response.statusCode
println "Received : $response.json"
```

And in `build.gradle`, put this script which pulls down the `groovy`, and `groovy-wslite` dependencies, and applies the shadow-jar plugin to bundle all dependencies into one single fat jar:

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "1.2.2"
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'example.Script'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
    compile 'com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2'
}
```

You can then (assuming you have installed Gradle), simply run:

```
gradle shadowJar
```

Which will compile your code, and put it and all its dependencies into `build/libs/myApp-all.jar`

So then, you can just run:

```
java -jar build/libs/myApp-all.jar
```

And your script should run as before...

You can then distribute this jar file, instead of just the script...

Hope this helps

Comment: Would you prefer using Gradle over Maven? I know there are ways to do this build process with Maven.

Comment: I always use Gradle...  It comes down to personal preference though, and there are many tools for the job

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest switching to Gradle or some other build tool that downloads the dependencies at build time.  As you probably already know grape pulls down all the dependencies at runtime.

> Grape (The Groovy Adaptable Packaging Engine or Groovy Advanced Packaging Engine) is the infrastructure enabling the grab() calls in Groovy, a set of classes leveraging Ivy to allow for a repository driven module system for Groovy. This allows a developer to write a script with an essentially arbitrary library requirement, and ship just the script. Grape will, **at runtime**, download as needed and link the named libraries and all dependencies forming a transitive closure when the script is run from existing repositories such as Ibiblio, Codehaus, and java.net.

This link might help you in your transition to using Gradle with your Groovy script.

[Running Groovy scripts from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360719/running-groovy-scripts-from-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

You could copy your Grape repo to the target deployment servers. Should be *~/.groovy/Grape*. Then you can keep your @Grabs in the scripts as is

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions

1. Replace the whole build progress with gradle, just like what's mentioned by @tim_yates' answer.
2. Use `grape install` command to pre-install the packages into the grape local repo, whose default path is "~/.groovy/grapes".Then package the scripts and the grape dir together. You might switch the grape repo dir to somewhere you prefer. See section 3.5 of http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html